# How to get object key for amazon s3 service

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a file stored in Amazon S3 with Java (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html), but I have problem with the object key as I don't know what it is.

The bucket name is `testbucket` and I have a folder with the name `files` in this bucket. If I have a file with the name `image.jpeg`; what is the object key?

```
private static String bucketName = "testbucket"; 
private static String key="files/image.jpeg";      


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    S3Object s3object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                bucketName, key));
     }
```

I get this output:

```
  21:43:54.054 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Sending Request: GET https://adap-demo.s3.amazonaws.com /report_templates/Testreport_1.jrxml
Headers: (User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.10.30 Linux/4.4.0-70-generic
OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.121-b13/1.8.0_121, Content-Type:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8, ) 
21:43:54.164 [main] DEBUG c.a.services.s3.internal.S3Signer - Calculated
string to sign:
"GET
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Sun, 02 Apr 2017 19:43:54 GMT
/adap-demo/report_templates/Testreport_1.jrxml"
Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered an
internal error while trying to communicate with S3, such as not being able
to access the network.
Error Message: Unable to calculate a request signature: Unable to   
calculate a request signature: Empty key
```

Comment: The key should be `files/image.jpeg`. To check the key click on the file and look at the link. It should be `https://s3-[region]..amazonaws.com/[bucket name]/[file key]`.

Comment: doesn't  not work and get 
Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered an
internal error while trying to communicate with S3, such as not being able
to access the network.
Error Message: Unable to calculate a request signature: Unable to   
calculate a request signature: Empty key

Comment: Apparently, you are passing an empty key to the function to retrieve the object. Can you please add the code you use to get the object to the question?

Comment: The code seems correct to me. Are your AWS credentials in place for the credentials provider (the file `~/.aws/credentials` should contain your credentials)? Also, there is a shorthand for [`getObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) if you only want to provide the object key and bucket name.

Comment: @Leon  Thanks for your help,it was credential issue.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: In your specific case, the object key is `files/image.jpg`

In technical terms, Amazon S3 is a simple **key-based object store**. When you store data, you assign a unique object key that can later be used to retrieve the data. **The S3 data model is a flat structure**: You create a bucket, and the bucket stores objects. There is no hierarchy of "subbuckets" or subfolders. However, you can infer logical hierarchy using key name prefixes.

In your case, the prefix is `files/` and the object name is `image.jpg`. The key is the prefix concatenated with the object name.

For example, a traditional file-based structure with directories that looks like this:

```
- files
    - index.html
    - images
        - logo.png
        - photo.jpg
```

Would translate to the following flat structure on S3, which each of the following lines representing the **key** of the respective objects:

```
files/index.html
files/images/logo.png
files/images/photo.jpg
```

You can learn more about the creation and usage of Amazon S3 object keys here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html